# How to retrieve the previous date and use it in a query?

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, select

I would like to retrieve the previous date (i.e., current date minus 1) and use it in a query through an = operator.

I got the following query to retrieve the previous date:
`select DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)`

It gives: **2011-03-14 00:00:00.000**

I would like to get only: **2011-03-14**, and use this in a query to check against a column's data.

Something like:
`select * from table where column1 in ('values list') and date=(previous_date)`

How can I combine the two and get it in the format I want?

Comment: r u doing sending the parameters value from application?if yes which application you are developing its in php or .net?

Comment: @Emaad: I'll be using .Net for this. And it might be from a script that I'll be using this query.

Comment: ok so you sending the parameters in that query,ryt?

Comment: You mean the date? I would like to retrieve it from the system and get the date before the current date and then check the table for the newly obtained date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got what I was looking for:

```
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), -1),120))
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

This might resolve your issue.

```
select * from table where 
column1 in ('values list') and 
DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, date), 0)=DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, GETDATE()), -1)
```

Comment: @Ashish: I need to equate the previous date with a date in the database. How can I do that?

Comment: date=(previous_date). Here you have previous_date in your custom format. You can change the format for you [Date] column to match it exactly like the previous date. This will resolve your issue. What's result for the above query I gave you?

Comment: I got an error :P :( My date in the database is in yyyy-mm-dd format and I need to get the previous date in the same format to compare them.

Comment: select DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
select DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0,  GETDATE()), -1) Try this. It will simply give you date for current date and previous date. Now you just need to replace your Datecolumn with GetDate()

Comment: It gives it with the time component, which is not present in my table. I want a way to extract only the date part.

Comment: select DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, date), 0) as CurrentDate,DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, date), -1) as PreviousDate
 from table. Execute this, It will list current and previous date in your datetime format.

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
   DECLARE @Date Datetime;


    SET @Date = DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, GETDATE()), -1);


   select * from table where column1 in ('values list') and Date = @Date
```

Regards

Comment: For some reason, getting the following error: Must declare the scalar variable "@Date".
Everything seems to be in order though.

Comment: I've discovered that when you edit your answer, the OP is not notified unless you address him/her in a comment (with `@nickname` notation, if it's a comment to your own answer).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where column1 in ('values list') 
and CAST(date as DATE)=CAST(DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DY, 0, GETDATE()), -1) as DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @date varchar(10);
SELECT @date=(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD,-1,GETDATE()),120))
select * from EMPOFFADDRESS where convert(varchar(10),entry`enter code here`date,120) = @date
```